# MYSQL - Match/Find a number in a string

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a need to find a particular number from a column, say I look for number `9` in table `tours` which has a column `city`. The column `city` has a string of numbers like

```
9
49
5,9
4,94
5,8,89,32
```

and I need to find the number 9 in these so the only results I would want would be

```
9
5,9
```

I have tried using REGEX but can't get it right. Can anyone point me to the right direction? Here's the query so far

```
SELECT 
    a.title, a.tourprice, a.city, b.city AS destCity
FROM
    tours a
        RIGHT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        id, city
    FROM
        destinations
    WHERE
        id = 47) b ON a.city LIKE CONCAT('%,', b.city) OR a.city LIKE CONCAT(b.city, ',%') //b.city evaluates to 9
```

I realize there may or may not always be a comma before or after the number I want.

Comment: Why not use `WHERE a.city LIKE '9,%' OR a.city LIKE '%,9,%' OR a.city LIKE '%,9'`? Else, I guess you may use `WHERE a.city REGEXP '[[:<:]]9[[:>:]]'`. *I'm tryed using REGEX but can't get it right.* - what regex did you try?

Comment: You should really think about [properly normalising that table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a MySQL built-in function, [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) which does what you want.

It returns the 1-based index of the first argument in the second argument, where the second argument is a comma-separated string. If the first argument isn't present in the second at all, it returns `0`.

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET(9, '9');           -- 1
SELECT FIND_IN_SET(9, '49');          -- 0
SELECT FIND_IN_SET(9, '5,9');         -- 2
SELECT FIND_IN_SET(9, '4,94');        -- 0
SELECT FIND_IN_SET(9, '5,8,89,32');   -- 0
SELECT FIND_IN_SET(9, '5,8,89,9,32'); -- 4
```

Since MySQL treats `0` as `FALSE` and any non-`0` number as `TRUE`, you can use it in a `WHERE` clause or in your `JOIN`.

```
RIGHT JOIN ... ON FIND_IN_SET(b.city, a.city)
```

But there are [several reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) why storing a comma-separated list like this is a bad idea. You should prefer a separate table with a row for each combination of tour and city.

Comment: Thanks a lot Matt. I'm marking yours as the correct answer due to the extra length you went to. I too, like the op of that question did it this way because it was simpler but I'll try to normalize the tables as much as possible in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Try this;)

```
SELECT
    a.title,
    a.tourprice,
    a.city,
    b.city AS destCity
FROM tours a
RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT id, city
    FROM `destinations`
    WHERE id = 47
) b ON FIND_IN_SET('9', a.city) > 0
```

And if `a.city` is not all separated by comma `,`, I think `REGEXP` will be more advisable, like the answer @Wiktor Stribiżew has given.

Answer (score 2):

I think you missed 1 possible scenario with `LIKE`: if a `9` appears in the *middle* of the entry. So, add

```
OR a.city LIKE CONCAT('%,', b.city, ',%')
```

If you want to have a go with a regex, try

```
WHERE a.city REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]', b.city, '[[:>:]]')
```

where the `[[:<:]]` is a leading and `[[:>:]]` is a trailing word boundaries. However, in such a simple situation, you can do without a REGEXP and use `LIKE` due to the fact that REGEXP in MySQL is rather resource-consuming.